# Is it ever appropriate to write $| \phi(t)>$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, notation

I am trying to solve the Schrodinger's wave equation $\hat H |\psi(x,t)> = E|\psi(x,t)>$ using separation variables so that

$\psi(x,t) = \psi(x)\phi(t)$

Solving the equation involves the step whereby I divide the $\psi(x)\phi(t)$ expression to get

$\frac{\hat H |\psi(x)>}{\psi(x)} = \frac{E|\psi(t)>}{\psi(t)}$

I am not sure whether writing it like this is appropriate. I'm not comfortable with the idea that we can have a state that is totally time dependent. Can someone evaluate whether it is appropriate to write using bra-ket like this?

Comment: You're mixing state vector and wavefunction. A state vector doesn't depend on position, it only depends on time: $|s(t)\rangle$. And the wavefunction is a projection of the state vector on the eigenvector of position operator:

$$\psi(x,t)=\langle x|s(t)\rangle.$$

Comment: Moreover, the Schrödinger equation that you use is actually the stationary state equation. It only applies if $\left|\psi\right>$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{H}$. Unless $\hat{H}$ has an explicit time dependence, $\left|\psi\right>$ will not depend on $t$.